# Does my customer have to install MySQL separately if my desktop application work with MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio

I am creating a desktop application using c++ in visual studio. Application should allow to store personal information such as id number, name, address, phone number and several other information in a MySQL database and it will allow to retrieve those information using id number. But my question is, does my client have to install MySQL separately in order to use my application? if so, how can I make my application work with database with the same features but without installing any applications separately?

Comment: Seems irrelevant to me. If your company has MySQL database installed and runing on some machine, your application just needs to connect to it using URL and some credentials. For that you don't need MySQL database on the client machine, just some lib that provides you MySQL API (but that can be part of your binary).

Comment: Did you try running your application without installing MySQL?

Comment: @pptaszni it is not a company mate. I am working solo and I don't want to make it an online application. If I am misunderstanding you, can you assist me?

Comment: @user253751 I am still at early stages of the development because without knowing about this I don't want to go further because if I get to know user has to install separately it will be hard to make changes.

Comment: If you don't want to make it an online app, then I assume you wish to store the information in the database that runs on the same machine as your client application. Then yes, you need to install, configure and run MySQL database on that machine. You can of course automate this process in your app, but it might be quite painful. Anyway, if you need to store only limited set of information (let's say hundreds of records, not millions), DB sounds like overkill. You can easily store it in a file with appropriate permissions.

Comment: @JayarajRohan My recommendation: Install MySQL and do some tutorials, so that you learn how MySQL works. It's a client/server product - you need a server to connect to. Where will the server be? You can run a MySQL server, or the user can run it on their own computer, or their IT guy can install it, etc... The client can be part of your app, but the server is always its own thing

Comment: @pptaszni ok it sounds good. Can you please give any link that I can follow to learn about storing in a file with appropriate permissions?

Comment: got it mate. Thank you @user253751

Comment: @JayarajRohan Use SQLite; be happy. It is a single-file full-featured database and used **everywhere**

Comment: You may want to use `sqlite` instead, if the database is less than a few GB and does not need stored proceedures.

Comment: @Botje a big thank you. It will help me.

Comment: @drescherjm a big thank you. It will help me.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/chmod - if you want to secure the file, give it chmod 600; you can use sqlite as already suggested, or https://github.com/nlohmann/json if your data is small and without complex relations